Polymorphic behavior of derived class objects in C++ STL list
I am storing objects of base and derives classes (Account, StudentAccount, EmployeeAccount) in an STL list and process them with STL Iterator. The dynamic polymorphic behavior of objects is not happening. After reading few post at this forum, it "seems" to me (since i am not much able to understand deep tech reasons) polymorphic behavior in STL list is not possible. I wanted to know if polymorphic behavior is not possible, what's the work around? If my perception is incorrect, please share a link or code sample. I am stuck in middle of a prototype. Below is the major code portion:
(using Visual Studio 2022 with ISO C++ 14, console application)
list<Account>* log = new list<Account>();  // in constructor

bool Bank::add(const Account& acc)
{
    // do some checking here
    this->log->push_back(Account(acc));
    return true;
}

bool Bank::addAccount(...parameter here...)
{
    return this->add(Account(...parameter here...));
}

bool Bank::addStudentAccount(...parameter here...)
{
    return this->add(StudentAccount(...parameter here...));
}


You seem to have misunderstood something... You need pointers to the polymorphic base class, not to the container. So you should have std::list<Account*> log; What you have now, with a list of Account objects, leads to object slicing.

And with that said, I recommend you use the owning smart pointers, like std::unique_ptr. As in std::list<std::unique_ptr<Account>> log; and log.push_back(std::make_unique<StudentAccount>(... optional parameters ...)):

Also, do you really need a list? The "default" container should almost always be std::vector. What are the requirements for your program? Why do you need to use a list instead of a vector?

Lastly some nitpicking: The abbreviation STL stands for the Standard Template Library, which is very different from the standard C++ library.

Thanks for your useful comment. No special reason choosing list over vector. Without knowing the inner tech details, i used list in a prototype few months back, so using it now again. Let me try out your suggestions.

@SyedIrfanAhmad list<Account>* log = new list<Account>(); -- Why are you using new to create a std::list<Account>?  Why not simply std::list<Account> log; or even std::list<Account*> log;?  C++ does not require new to create objects.  C++ is not Java, C#, python, or any other language that requires new to create objects.  If you are using some other computer language to figure out C++, it will not work out too well.  You will end up with 1) Buggy programs, 2) Inefficient programs, or 3) Programs that will look weird to a C++ programmer.

Thanks @Some programmer dude and @PaulMcKenzie, polymorphic behavior is achieved. There are two errors that i am unable to fix in the below method. This is the copied code from this forum. Below method was working when std::list<Account*>::iterator it; was declared as std::list<Account>::iterator it; Now error is appearing:
(1) at the = that is at the left of std::find_if(). Error: No operator = matches operands
(2) at the "&" of statement return &*it; Error: return value does not match the function type

Account* Khata::getAccount(int accountNumber) const
{
std::list<Account*>::iterator it;
it = std::find_if(this->log.begin(),
this->log.end(),
[&] (Account const& acc) { return (acc.getNumber() == accountNumber); });
if (it != this->log.end())
return &*it;
else
return nullptr;
}

Use type-deduction, as in auto it = std::find_if(log.begin(), log.end(), ...);, and you won't have to worry about typos in long type-names.

But if you have a new problem, then please post it as a new question.

Many thanks @Someprogrammerdude. All issues are fixed now.

list<Account>* log = new list<Account>()

This is called "slicing": if you put a derived class into that list, only the Account "sub-part" is actually stored there. Same if you copy a StudentAccount to an Account -- the Student-part simply gets "sliced off" because it has no place to go.
The way around this is very simple: store pointers.
#include <list>
#include <memory>

...

typedef std::unique_ptr<Account> AccountPtr;
typedef std::list<AccountPtr> List;
List* log=new List;

bool Bank::add(AccountPtr acc)
{
    // do some checking here
    this->log->push_back(std::move(acc));
    return true;
}

bool Bank::addAccount(...parameter here...)
{
    return this->add(std::make_unique<Account>(...parameter here...));
}

bool Bank::addStudentAccount(...parameter here...)
{
    return this->add(std::make_unique<StudentAccount>(...parameter here...));
}


Thanks @Christian Stieber. Things have started working as i have mentioned in my comment under the question. Please have a look at the last comment where i have mentioned that i couldn't fix two errors. Sorry, i tried to format code block but somehow, it is not happening. Selecting code and pressing Ctrl+K takes the cursor in the browser address bar the formatting bar is not appearing while entering comment.

When you say "store pointers", it may be worth expanding to say that smart pointers (std::unique_ptr, etc) and associated helper functions are preferable (less error prone) than using "raw" pointers.

I think one of the comments above has answered your question to a degree. To repeat, polymorphism is only possible when using a pointer to the base class for  method invocation - in this case a pointer of type "Account *"
On a side note - I strongly suggest playing with polymorphism to get used to the idea before you jump into combining it with Templates. It will make life much easier even if its only a prototype.
I wish you the best in your C++ journey!!
